# invert_xaxis gives an error when using matplotlib plt.barh

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am trying to plot 2 way bar charts. I want to invert the x-axis of `x1` so that 0 is in the middle of both. I keep getting the error:

> AttributeError: 'BarContainer' object has no attribute 'invert_xaxis'

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y = ['F','M','H']
x1 = [8, 4, 3]
x2 = [2, 4, 7]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharey=True)
axes[0] = plt.barh(y, x1, align='center', color='b')
axes[1] = plt.barh(y, x2, align='center', color='r')
axes[0].invert_xaxis()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are assigning the plots to the two axis objects instead of using them to plot. The correct way is to directly use the axis objects to plot the `barh`. Then the things will work as expected.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = ['F','M','H']
x1 = [8, 4, 3]
x2 = [2, 4, 7]
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2, sharey=True)
axes[0].barh(y, x1, align='center', color='b') # <---- Changed here
axes[1].barh(y, x2, align='center', color='r') # <---- Changed here
axes[0].invert_xaxis()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @AlexandraSilva: You are welcome. Thanks for providing a complete example